# Why does the attr method not work in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have this input clear its value when I click on it, but I get no results.

**The HTML:**

```
<input id='input' type="text" name="phppostvar" value="clear this"></input>
```

**The jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
$('#input').click(function(){

    var value = $('#input').attr('value');

    if (value === "clear this") {
        $('#input').attr('value','');
    }

});
```

Comment: I would try and use .val() not .attr('value','')

Comment: Or use the `placeholder` attribute

Comment: Removing the value whenever the user clicks on the input is a terrible idea. They might be clicking between a couple of specific letters in order to correct a typo.

Comment: Your example does work. It may not be advisable to use, but you can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/4fT78/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the `placeholder` attribute, or a very simple JS solution:

```
document.getElementById("input").onfocus = function() {
    this.value = this.value == "clear this" ? "" : this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#input').click(function(){
 if ($(this).val() === "clear this") {
    $(this).val('');
 }
 });
```